# VBA to Create PDF for excel sheets based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

So I have a dashboard report that shows the sale performance based on my drop down selection from another sheet (Name Key).  In Cell "B266" It has the total sales from the current month.  I have working on a VBA that will create the PDF report and save it if the following conditions are met:

**1.** In the name key drop down look up it doesn't say "Exclude" (I have exclude for salespeople who were not including in reporting)
**2.** When that value is selected in the sheet where the report is (INDIVIDUAL PERFORMANCE SUMMARY) with the drop down location $A$7, cell b266 on the report sheet isn't 0.

If these two conditions are met, create a pdf and save if not skip to the next cell in the selection.  I have following code:

```
Sub PDF_Generator()

Dim cell As Range
Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
Dim counter As Long

Set wsSummary = Sheets("INDIVIDUAL PERFORMANCE SUMMARY")

For Each cell In Worksheets("NAME KEY").Range("$H2:$H60")
  If cell.Value <> "Exclude" Then
     'progress in status bar
     counter = counter + 1
     Application.StatusBar = "Processing file: " & counter & "/1042"
  If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INDIVIDUAL PERFORMANCE SUMMARY").Range("C1") <> "TRUE" Then
  counter = counter + 1
     Application.StatusBar = "Processing file: " & counter & "/1042"
     With wsSummary
        .Range("$A$7").Value = cell.Value
        .ExportAsFixedFormat _
              Type:=xlTypePDF, _
              Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INDIVIDUAL PERFORMANCE SUMMARY").Range("J1").Value & _
      "\" & cell.Value & ".pdf", _
              Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
              IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
              IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
              OpenAfterPublish:=False
     End With
  End If
  End If
Next cell

 Set wsSummary = Nothing
End Sub
```

I'm still very new to VBA please help this will save me a lot of time.

Comment: You didn't say what is failing/not working.

Comment: Didn't you ask this/similar yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081548/how-to-make-my-automated-pdf-creator-skip-drowdown-selections-where-a-certain-ro

Comment: Yes, I didn't get a response so I re-asked it I really need help.  @Nelly27281 it's still just creating PDF's for every dropdown selection and is only acknowledging the "Exclude" but not if the value at B266 is 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87420/discussion-between-user3666237-and-findwindow).

Comment: Does your IF work? If so, it's just the print to pdf part? How are we supposed to help you when we don,t even know what the thing you,re trying to print looks like?

Comment: @DavidG  The If works but not the second IF to skip creating PDFs for files that have zero values in cell B266 after the selection has changed

Comment: Does the pdf print correctly when it prints? I need to leave work but the best thing would be for you to write what is happening when you debug. Where are the errors, what's going wrong, etc. Then people will assist you.

Comment: @DavidG yes the PDFS are created correctly but I going to sift thru almost 200 names so If I can skip the ones and not create Pdfs for when the value is zero at that cell for that criteria will be awesome.

Comment: Well have you tried to add another if; If sheet.range("b226").value <> 0 then

Comment: @DavidG Maybe I have to change the logic because when I add that IF nothing happens is it because the value in b226 is a vlookup?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** (based on the comment)**:**

Add one more IF condition below your 2nd condition:

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INDIVIDUAL PERFORMANCE SUMMARY").Range("C1") <> "TRUE" Then
    If (sheet.range("B226").value <> 0) Then
        'your code to create PDF
    End If
End If
```

This way the code won't create PDF if B226 is 0.

Comment: I want to code to continue running thru the list of names just skips the ones where the B226 is 0 and don't create a PDF.

Comment: So you don't want both the conditions in one IF?

Comment: Yeah so for example let say the first name in the dropdown is Alfred, b266 is 1000 create the pdf the next name is bryan and b266 is 0 skip creating the pdf and the next name is carl and b266 is 15 create the pdf

Comment: So insert that under line Application.StatusBar?

Comment: appreciate the help now I'm getting Compile error:  Next without For

Comment: Can you assist I'm getting a error that says Compile error: Next without For

Comment: @user3666237 , I am not assisting because I don't see your effort hear. Show me what have you tried with my suggestion.

Comment: I added the line like you said and share with you the result  I will write the full code in your answer edit

Answer (score 0):

Add and AND statement and logic test for B226<>0

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INDIVIDUAL PERFORMANCE SUMMARY").Range("C1") <> "TRUE" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INDIVIDUAL PERFORMANCE SUMMARY).Range("B226").value <> 0 Then
```